# freq argument options in statsmodels tsa AR and ARMA models

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

In the statsmodels time series analysis [AR](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR.html#statsmodels.tsa.ar_model.AR) and [ARMA](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA) models, the `freq` argument can be "a Pandas offset or ‘B’, ‘D’, ‘W’, ‘M’, ‘A’, or ‘Q’."

What do ‘B’, ‘D’, ‘W’, ‘M’, ‘A’, and ‘Q’ mean? I'm guessing that D is 'daily', W is 'weekly', M is 'monthly', A is 'annually', and that Q is 'quarterly', but I can't figure out what B is, and I can't find any documentation that confirms (or disconfirms) my guesses.

Answer (score 9):

It is documented in their super class [`statsmodels.tsa.base.tsa_model.TimeSeriesModel`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py).

```
"""
Timeseries model base class

Parameters
----------
endog
exog
dates
freq : str {'B','D','W','M','A', 'Q'}
    'B' - business day, ie., Mon. - Fri.
    'D' - daily
    'W' - weekly
    'M' - monthly
    'A' - annual
    'Q' - quarterly

"""
```